# Fixar header no topo ao rolar página

Tags: html, css

Há um tempo estava procurando como colocar header e footer fixos no topo e no final da página, respectivamente, se ajustando ao conteúdo que ficaria entre dos dois, e consegui com o seguinte código:

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#container {
    background: red;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    background: blue;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
    height: 52px;
    background: black;
}
header div {
    width: 1000px;
    background: red;
    height: 52px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <div id="container">
                <header>
                    <div></div>
                </header>
                <div id="content"></div><!--content-->
            </div><!--container-->
</div><!--wrapper-->
```

Gostaria de saber como, usando esse código, posso fixar o header no topo ao rolar a página, mas manter a estrutura do **content** e do **footer**.

Comment: O que significa "manter a estrutura do content e do footer"?

Comment: O content seria oque fica entre o header e o footer, que vai se ajustar independente do tamanho, e mesmo assim o footer ficaria no rodapé fixo, e o header no topo ....

Comment: Creio que é o que o @Daniel respondeu então. A única coisa que tem que acrescentar é um padding no content, em cima e embaixo do mesmo tamanho do footer e do header, assim o começo e o fim do content não vão ficar encobertos.

Comment: Eu acabei de ver a demo no JsFiddle, mas o footer também tá fixo, era só o header, por exemplo, como é no Facebook e Youtube, o header com a barra de busca fica fixo e acompanha a rolagem do site, mas não o footer, o footer fican o final da página, entendeu?

Comment: Essas coisas você tem que colocar sempre no corpo da pergunta, pois eu também só entendi pelos comentários aqui embaixo. Procure nas próximas descrever melhor o problema, aí a gente consegue te ajudar melhor e ao mesmo tempo quem for responder não perde tempo com coisa que não te é útil. Mas a solução é simples, ele colocou uma entrada no CSS para o header e outra para o footer. Basta não usar a do footer. Se quiser que o footer fique no pé da página quando esta for menor que a tela, basta um min-height:100% e altura do body e html com 100% também.

Comment: Sim,usei só o trecho do header, e funcionou , fica fixo e acompanhando a rolagem da página, mas ele tá "encobrindo" o padding que eu dei no texto que estava dentro do "content" , como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Aumentando o padding top do content pro tamanho do header, e mais o espaço que você quiser.

Comment: Obrigado, fiz isso, só que pensei que fosse gambiara haha, mas valeu

Answer (score 2):

Uma das soluções seria posicionar o header como `position:fixed` para que o `header` tenha as propriedades `top`e `left` relativas ao `window`. E usando as medidas `vw` (Viewport width) e `vh` (Viewport height) você pode posicionar facilmente um elemento na viewport (área visível do browser). Abaixo um exemplo (bem resumido) do que você pode fazer para posicionar esses elementos da maneia desejada.

```
header{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
}

footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Segue um exemplo funcionando:

https://jsfiddle.net/kvkw1eex/1/

Comment: O Footer nesse caso também está "encobrindo" o conteúdo com a rolagem, mas no caso era pra ser só o header, como é no facebook e youtube, que a barra de busca acompanha a rolagem, mas o footer fica no final da página.

Comment: Nesse caso, você não especifica o `position` do footer. Deixa ele sem as propriedades, `position`, `top` e  `left`. Que ele irá seguir a ordem dos elementos. É que você havia citado no título `header e footer fixos` por isso coloquei o `position:fixed;` no  footer também.